# R - can install package alr3 but get error when loading library in R script

Tags: r

How can i get the alr3 package to install and run?

Running on R Studio 1.1 for Windows. Installed package 'alr3' via Tools->Install Packages.

When I type the following I get error - 'readxl' not found.

> > library(alr3)

Loading required package: car
Loading required package: carData
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘car’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘readxl’
Error: package ‘car’ could not be loaded

Tried loading 'readxl' (via Tools->Install Packages) but get error :

> > install.packages("readxl")

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/readxl_1.0.0.zip'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/readxl_1.0.0.zip': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/readxl_1.0.0.zip'
Warning in install.packages :
  download of package ‘readxl’ failed

Comment: I sometimes find that when an installation fails like this,  it works for me to download the zip file directly from CRAN and then install using "Install packages from local zips"

Comment: hmm..looks like readxl is missing now even from the tidyverse package. Maybe its been pulled out by the authors?? Anyway, I cant find the readxl file.

Comment: Try https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readxl/index.html

Comment: Thx much for pointing the way. I was able to download the 'readxl' package and install it via R studio. Got readxl from https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/readxl/index.html.